# Using nRF8001 as a master with an FPGA

Tags: fpga, serial, bluetooth-low-energy

I would like to use Nordic's nRF8001 modules in Master and Slave modes and also would like to connect it with Spartan-3E FPGAs using SPI. I am considering buying the [nRF8001 DevKit](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/nrf8001-development-kit/44060?mpart=NRF8001-DK&vendor=1490&WT.z_ref_page_type=PS&WT.z_ref_page_sub_type=PD&WT.z_ref_page_id=PD&WT.z_ref_page_event=DC_Link_Table).

I believe it is required by BLE standards that a device can be programmed as a Master or a Slave but in [Nordic website](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF8001) it is stated that the nRF8001 module is "Cost-optimized solution for Peripheral (Slave) role operation". Also in the *nRF8001 DevKit* contents section (the first link) it specifically says the kit contains "1x Bluetooth low energy master emulator". These expressions have confused me and also I couldn't see any expression similar to "can be used both as a master or as a slave".

I would like to develop my application using the boards found in the DevKit but in the end I would like to connect bare nRF8001 samples through SPI to FPGAs and use one as a Master and one as a Slave. My budget is fairly limited so it would be very convenient for me to finish this project using only one DevKit.

Is it possible to do so with the nRF8001 DevKit and nRF8001 SDK or do I need to use different products and/or different programming environments?

Comment: I only briefly looked at the nRF8001s so I'm not sure, but I think the modules are only really meant for slaves. I don't think they're able to function as masters. The 'master emulator' may or may not be related to the nRF8001, more so a development aid in the absence of another BLE master to play with.

Comment: I have one of those nRF8001 devkits. The 'master emulator' is a little usb dongle device which is controlled by the demo/test software included with the kit. As far as I remember there is no way to make the nRF8001 behave as a BLE master.